# How do I rewrite this function now that it needs to call upon a method in a class from a different file?

Tags: python, class, methods

Here is the function (it's in a file, "worldmodel.py"):

```
def add_entity(world, entity):
   pt = entities.get_position(entity)
   if within_bounds(world, pt):
      old_entity = occ_grid.get_cell(world.occupancy, pt)
      if old_entity != None:
         entities.clear_pending_actions(old_entity)
      occ_grid.set_cell(world.occupancy, pt, entity)
      world.entities.append(entity)
```

And here is the class in a file named, "occ_grid.py":

```
class Grid:
   def __init__(self, width, height, occupancy_value):
      self.width = width
      self.height = height
      self.cells = []

      # initialize grid to all specified occupancy value
      for row in range(0, self.height):
         self.cells.append([])
         for col in range(0, self.width):
            self.cells[row].append(occupancy_value)

   def set_cell(self, point, value):
      self.cells[point.y][point.x] = value
```

My question is, how would I rewrite the line of code in "def add_entity" that refers to "set_cell"? (Now that I've made set_cell a method of the class Grid) NOTE: Before I made set_cell part of the grid class, it was a function outside of the class (but still in the same file as the class) Thanks!

Comment: What is `occ_grid` in `add_entity`?  You can only call the method on an instance of `Grid`.  Do you have an instance of `Grid`?

Comment: I haven't modified the code in the function yet, so I believe the occ_grid refers to the file "occ_grid.py". (set_cell used to be a function outside of the grid class, and it was still in the occ_grid.py file) I'm confused on what to do exactly. :( Do I make an instance of grid in the add_entity function? What would that look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to `import occ_grid` in your `worldmodel.py`, then instantiate a `Grid` object and call that objects `set_cell()`-method. The `add_entity` needs to get the `Grid`-object as its parameter unless it can safely instantiate new ones at will.

Here's a naive example which does not work but demonstrates what I mean:

```
import occ_grid

g = occ_grid.Grid(your_width, your_height, occupancy)

def add_entity(world, entity, grid):
    pt = entities.get_position(entity)
    if within_bounds(world, pt):
        old_entity = grid.get_cell(world.occupancy, pt)
        if old_entity != None:
            entities.clear_pending_actions(old_entity)
        grid.set_cell(world.occupancy, pt, entity)
        world.entities.append(entity)

add_entity(world, entity, g)
```

Comment: Should it be, "g.set_cell(pt, entity)? (On the third to last line)

Comment: No, you see on the last line, we're calling the `add_entity()`-function and *passing* the grid object `g` to the function. The `add_entity()` function just expects a third argument that we've named as `grid`. You could just as well define the function to accept `world, entity, duck`. They key here is that when we call that function, we give it a grid-object (in this case `g`) as the third argument.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here, (1) calling functions across modules and (2) calling methods of classes. 
It seems you can already do (1).

The trick is that although methods are defined as

```
 def methodName(self, ...)
```

They are *called* as

```
 object.methodName(...)
```

And object implicitly becomes the "self" Parameter.  Here is an example:

```
import occ_grid  # Import the module (file) that contains Grid.
   .
   .   
world.occupancy = occ_grid.Grid()  # Create an instance of Grid.
   .
   .
def add_entity(world, entity):
   pt = entities.get_position(entity)       
   .
   .   
   world.occupancy.set_cell(pt, entity)
```

In this example, `grid` is a global variable, which is probably not a good design.  I guess it should be a property of `world`, but that's only a guess.

Comment: Ahh I see. I just want to make sure, but the parameters in  occ_grid.set_cell(world.occupancy, pt, entity) would change to just pt and entity right?

Comment: Of course you can name paramters how you like.  But I have corrected my example to more closely match your code.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you make the `set_cell` function a static method of the `Grid` class, you're going to need and *instance* of `Grid`.

```
from occ_grid import Grid
```

I am going to make an assumption here, and say that your want your grid to be part of the world? Either way, this is an example of instantiating that class.

```
class World:
    grid = Grid()

    def add_entity(world, entity):
        # All that other stuff.
        world.grid.set_cell(pt, entity)
```